# TabBar app with MapView (where do i have to download the info and how to show that info in the MapView?))

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, nsurlconnection

My app consist in a TabBarController with a MapView and a TableView such controllers. The info that it'll be showed in the views has to be downloaded via NSURLConnection, and it takes a long time. I have doubts about:

I'll have a class (NSObject) that will download the data and parser it. But both the map (with annotations) and the table need this info to show.

- Where do I have to download the data? Between other problems, the map appears before download the data, so how can I update the map with the annotations?

**UPDATED:**

Ok, maybe I need to explain better. 
My app download the info using the reverse user location, so in the AppDelegate.m I use the locationManager.
The locationManagerDelegate is conformed by the Downloader.m (that via NSURLConnection takes the info). 
So far, the mapView appears in the screen, of course empty cause it doesn't have the info so the annotations property is empty.
Once the Downloader finish downloading the info, I need to set the annotations in the map. Bu how. I mean, i dont have an instance of mapViewController in the Downloader.m. The place where I created one was in the appDelegate.
My big problem is the places where i have to do the tasks (appDelegate.m, Downloader.m, mapViewController.m) and because i'm gonna have both a mapView and a tableView, I need the information that it was downloaded for both of them.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

ok i will try to answer your question according to what i understand :)

i assume that you are using the delegate methods of NSURLConnection and your final method is :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

this is the place where you are going to handle all your data because this method means that all the data have been retrieved from the server.

so for your final answer about the annotations, since you are going to retrieve data by NSURLConnection than you are going to implement your code like :

```
MKCoordinateSpan coordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01);
MKCoordinateRegion coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerPoint, coordinateSpan);

[noteMap setRegion:coordinateRegion];
[noteMap regionThatFits:coordinateRegion]; //this is the center and region of your map

MyLocation *annotation = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:"annotation-name" address:"your-subtitle" coordinate:cordPoint] ; //this is an annotation class that i implemented
["your-map-view" addAnnotation:annotation]; //this is the method for adding annotation
```

i wish that this code above fits what you require..

Comment: ok if i were you when the download has finished , i'll write them to an array which is appdelegate's attribute and then initialize my map in appdelegate or maybe in the first view controller ..
hope that solves your problem..